# Where do I find the SUDO_COMMAND environment variable?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I'm currently learning the foundations of Linux with Ubuntu and there is a little activity where I need to find information about environment variables. I already found 6/7 info but just can't find `SUDO_COMMAND`. this is how the list goes:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=student
SUDO_COMMAND=
PWD=/home
HOME=/home/student
LOGNAME=student
OLDPWD=/home/student
```

I noticed that the information comes in order and the `SUDO_COMMAND` is between user and pwd. did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: do you have sudo privileges?

Answer (score 12):

`SUDO_COMMAND` is an environment variable set by `sudo` only in the environment of the process started by it (and inherited by any child processes). If you run `sudo some-command arg1 arg2`, then `SUDO_COMMAND` will contain the absolute path to `some-command`, and `arg1 arg2`. If you ran `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`, then the variable will be set to the shell that was started. In any case, you probably won't see it outside of a process tree started by `sudo`.

For example:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo $SUDO_COMMAND'
/bin/sh -c echo $SUDO_COMMAND
```

Or:

```
$ sudo env
HOME=/home/muru
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
TERM=xterm-256color
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
MAIL=/var/mail/root
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
USERNAME=root
SHELL=/bin/bash
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/env
SUDO_USER=muru
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=1000
```

---

> I noticed that the information comes in order

I don't know which command you're using, but you cannot rely on the output of `set`, `declare`, `env` or `printenv` to be in some order.

Comment: And I thought `sudo echo $SUDO_COMMAND` could be used to create an infinitive loop… :(

Answer (score 5):

The `SUDO_COMMAND` is an environment variable which *Set to the command run by sudo*.

As mentioned by @muru - if `sudo` execute a new shell - this environment variable will be shown in this new shell

#### More info

[`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudo.8) provides the following details:

```
ENVIRONMENT
 sudo utilizes the following environment variables.  The security policy
 has control over the actual content of the command's environment.

 EDITOR           Default editor to use in -e (sudoedit) mode if neither
                  SUDO_EDITOR nor VISUAL is set.

 MAIL             Set to the mail spool of the target user when the -i
                  option is specified or when env_reset is enabled in
                  sudoers (unless MAIL is present in the env_keep list).

 HOME             Set to the home directory of the target user when the -i
                  or -H options are specified, when the -s option is
                  specified and set_home is set in sudoers, when
                  always_set_home is enabled in sudoers, or when env_reset
                  is enabled in sudoers and HOME is not present in the
                  env_keep list.

 LOGNAME          Set to the login name of the target user when the -i
                  option is specified, when the set_logname option is
                  enabled in sudoers or when the env_reset option is
                  enabled in sudoers (unless LOGNAME is present in the
                  env_keep list).

 PATH             May be overridden by the security policy.

 SHELL            Used to determine shell to run with -s option.

 SUDO_ASKPASS     Specifies the path to a helper program used to read the
                  password if no terminal is available or if the -A option
                  is specified.

 SUDO_COMMAND     Set to the command run by sudo.
```

Comment: I don't think your example is actually reproducible. `SUDO_COMMAND` only exists in the environment started by `sudo`, if `SUDO_COMMAND` actually where `/bin/ls`, then you wouldn't get a shell to run `echo $SUDO_COMMAND`.